# What will a thread do when it is blocked

Tags: java, concurrency

I want to know what a thread will do when the lock is held by another thread.
Does it retry to acquire the lock?
If the answer is yes, then if it will wait a moment between the two retry, and how long is the retry-period ?
If the answer is no, then how it know when the lock is released ?

**== update ==**
I am talking about the lock create by *synchronized* , which is called [Intrinsic Lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html).

Comment: Depends on the lock implementation and system on which it is running.

Comment: In the BLOCKED state, a thread is about to enter a synchronized block, but there is another thread currently running inside a synchronized block on the same object. The first thread must then wait for the second thread to exit its block. Then,it notifies.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Do your have any authoritative link to prove your opinion,  because I can't find any explanation about this from the Oracle website.

Comment: It’s not an opinion. A lock is a concept, not a specific thing, unless you specify which specific lock you’re talking about. quartata already explained some differences.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I am talking about the lock create by synchronized , whick is called Intrinsic Lock on *Java Concurrency Pratice*.

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally, there are two common types of locks:

- spin locks: this is akin to what you're describing; the thread will loop (perhaps with an implementation-dependant sleep thrown in) until the lock is released, constantly polling it while waiting.
- mutex locks: This uses some sort of kernel resource -- the specifics are dependant on the OS, but in general the kernel is responsible for putting the thread to sleep (blocking) and waking it up when the mutex is available.

As far as I'm aware, all of Java's locks work the second way -- the kernel knows when the mutex is released by another thread and reschedules the waiting thread. Your code will only run again when the lock is ready.

You may see spin locks in lower level code (like the kernel itself!), or places where the wait time is going to be so short there's no point in putting the thread to sleep to wait for it to be released (That only works if the system has more than one core though, since otherwise it can't run the thread that needs to release the lock and the one waiting for it simultaneously -- it'll have to reschedule)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found some similar description from *Java Concurrency Pratice*, but I still have some doubt. When using mutex locks, how JVM decide which thread should be awaked firsted, asuming that all the threads have the same priority? Besides, it's better for you to add some authoritative link to prove your opinion, because I can't find any explanation from the Oracle website.

Comment: *"When using mutex locks, how JVM decide which thread should be awaked firsted, asuming that all the threads have the same priority?"* - Unspecified.  Indeterminate.  *" Besides, it's better for you to add some authoritative link to prove your opinion, because I can't find any explanation from the Oracle website."* - Read the JVM source code.  That is definitive.